# webRTC ice server not working on different network

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io, webrtc, peerjs

I am new to webrtc peer js developer, I just implemented API as per peerjs.com demo but my application and demo is working fine on machines on same network internet but when i change one peer on other city or network and one on other then communication not working and nor receiving any error, Can you please suggest.

Demo link: https://jmcker.github.io/Peer-to-Peer-Cue-System/

i have already used free turn stun server in my example for testing but stil no luck to communicate.

```
     peer = new Peer(my_peer_id, {
        config: {'iceServers': [{urls:["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]}
        ]} /* Sample servers, please use appropriate ones */
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a TURN-Server like CoTurn in that case. 
After installing you can simply add this server into your config.

The TURN will relay the traffic if a direct P2P-Connection can't be stablished (Company Network, Firewall, ..)